# Saving association with existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

Im building a movie ticketing app in which I have movies and each movie has many showtimes.

This is my movie class:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :showtimes, dependent: :destroy

end
```

and showtime class

```
class Showtime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :movie

end
```

In my showtime form I have the following field

```
<%= f.collection_select :movie, Movie.all, :id, :title %>
```

In my showtime controller do I have the following create method

```
  def create
    @showtime = Showtime.new(showtime_params)
    if @showtime.save
      redirect_to @showtime, notice: 'Showtime was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def showtime_params
    params.require(:showtime).permit(:movie_id, :start_time)
  end
```

I this the correct approach to saving that association?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work if you change to movie_id but I prefer to use options_for select:

```
<%= f.select :movie_id, options_for_select(Movie.choices) %>
```

and in your movie.rb

```
def self.choices
   options = []
   Movie.find_each do |movie|
     options << [movie.title, movie.id]
   end
   options
end
```

Comment: What is the advantage of doing it this way?

Comment: Just a personal preference. I find it easier to remember than looking up the order or arguments for collection_for_select. options for select can take a one dimensional array or, if you want to display a different value (a name instead of an id, like above), a two-dimensional array. I don't like methods that require lots of arguments, I guess. Either way works, though.

Answer (score 0):

Since showtime_params permits :movie_id thats the name you have to give to your collection field:

```
<%= f.collection_select :movie_id, Movie.all, :id, :title %>
```